# How can I set path to myException.java in client?, when create client from WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, fault

I have server, server methods throw my exception - MBFault:

```
import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(name = "fault.MBFault", 
        targetNamespace = "fault")
public class MBFault extends Exception {

    private String detail;

    public MBFault(String message, String detail) {
        super(message);
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public MBFault(String message, String detail, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
}
```

The server-based I create a WSDL, From the WSDL I create client (wsimport -s myPackage ...wsdl).
How can I set path to MBFault in client? If I want, that MBFault.java save in package "fault", and all other in package "otherClasses" in client. Help me, please.

Comment: Have you tried simply giving `MBFault` a proper java-style package?

Comment: What is "java-style package" ?

Comment: I mean place `MBFault` in a package, i.e. `package you.foo.exception`. This will be the default namespace of the artifact when it's generated

Comment: MBFault has package (package example.fault), but file MBFault created in folder with @WebService, May be this problem can solve with jab:binding, jax-ws:binding...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to make the following change:

```
@WebFault(
        name            = "MBFault", 
        targetNamespace = "http://fault"
)
```

See more in [*Java API for XML Web Services Annotations*](https://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/annotations.html).

Comment: when set targetNamespace = "http: //fault", create folder "fault" with class ObjectFactory, but I need create class MBFault in folder "fault"...